# How to shutdown eclipse instances programmatically

Tags: eclipse

How to shutdown eclipse instances programmatically:

When we switch over to different eclipse versions, sometimes current running instance of eclipse doesn't allow to restart the different eclipse instance.

It says already an eclipse instance is running...  Therefore it is not allowing the other instance of eclipse to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are speaking about programatically close Eclipse within an Eclipse plugin, you can use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close();
```

See the documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbench.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can close Eclipse in a plugin using:

```java
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

workbench.close();
```

If you have the `IApplication` object you can also use

```
IApplication.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use `Java Runtime` to execute the following command :

```
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM eclipse.exe /T");
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```